# Desktop environments not working on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, kde, desktop-environment, gdm

I did a fresh arch uefi install and everything went smoothly. Then i moved ahead to installing `xorg` and `gnome`
It was also completed with no errors.
Now when I run:

```
systemctl start gdm
```

The system showed some errors:
[this is the error it showed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAOJd.jpg).
And my laptop shut down.
I tried installing plasma and sddm but same result when i do:

```
systemctl start sddm
```

Issuing the command `lspci -k` also gives the same error and results in system shutdown.

I have a HP Pavilion gaming laptop i5 9th gen and a nvidia gtx1050 GPU.
This is the first time I installed arch and really want to use it with gnome.

PS: Apart from this issue, the base arch from console is running fine. I installed manjaro a while back with gnome and it also seemed to have this error as it would shut down after some time of showing the HP logo.

Answer (score 0):

If you have gnome installed does starting wayland on the command line work, not using GDM? Most likely you saw at least some info [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME#Wayland_sessions):

```
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland dbus-run-session gnome-session
```